# Exclude And Operations Conditions Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i want to AND and put all exclude query in one exclude function.

```
context['users'] = User.objects.exclude(userprofile__user_role__role_title='Super Admin').exclude(userprofile__user_is_deleted = True).exclude(is_superuser=True)
```

Above i have two exclude instead i want one

```
context['users'] = User.objects.exclude(userprofile__user_role__role_title='Super Admin', userprofile__user_is_deleted = True, is_superuser=True)
```

But it is not working in my view

Comment: what it return?

Comment: user_is_deleted not working This is not working

Comment: can you give the output in terminal/console `test = User.objects.exclude(role_title='Super Admin', user_is_deleted = False) print(test)`

Comment: when im using this `context['users'] = User.objects.exclude(userprofile__user_role__role_title='Super Admin').exclude(userprofile__user_is_deleted = True).exclude(is_superuser=True)
       ` it is giving right Output

Comment: `User.objects.exclude(userprofile__user_role__role_title='Super Admin', userprofile__user_is_deleted = True, is_superuser=True)` this should work

Comment: no its not working

Comment: can you add the sql query. `User.objects.exclude(userprofile__user_role__role_title='Super Admin', userprofile__user_is_deleted = True, is_superuser=True)` print test.query`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separating all queries by a comma works like AND, if you want combine multiple AND/OR operations you can use Q objects in Django.

e.g.

```
from django.db.models import Q

context['users'] = User.objects.exclude((Q(userprofile__user_role__role_title='Super Admin') & Q(is_superuser=True)) | Q(userprofile__user_is_deleted = True))
```

The reason why it might not be working for you is that maybe you are using a wrong query? Possible reasons maybe:

1. Matching 'Super Admin', it may be stored in lowercase or something? try using `icontains` and using lower case 'super admin'
2. There is no user which has 'Super Admin' as title, is deleted and is superuser at the same time? Try querying all the objects one by one, see if there is an intersection?

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: what is the different between `&` `|` because `|` is working as AND

Comment: & = AND while | = OR, | is not be working as AND, if you see carefully, the example I gave has modified query and not actual query, the query in example translates to (title=Super Admin AND is_superuser) OR is_deleted, while your query translated to (title=Super Admin AND is_superuser AND is_deleted)

Maybe it's because of modified query?

Answer (score -1):

you can try with Q()

```
from django.db.models import Q

User.objects.exclude(Q(role_title='Super Admin')| Q(user_is_deleted = False))
```